# I can't indent my file indentation

Tags: files, gedit, emacs

I write C file on Emacs and I'm using 4 tab width for my files. In Emacs, I see that my file is indented with 4 tab-width. But when I try to read my file with cat command, I see that my file is indented with 8 tab-width.

First, I thought it is because of Emacs, then opened file with Gedit and re-indented file from 8 tab-width to 4 tab-width and saved it. But still, when I read my file from terminal or push it to Github or whatever, it is indented with 8 tab-width.

File on Emacs:

[image: File on Emacs]

File on Gedit:

[image: File on Gedit]

What can override my file, after my savings?
Are there any global variable for modifying tab-width on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains TAB-characters (ascii-code 9, unicode 0009).

emacs interprets these and displays them aligned to 4-character borders.
The general norm is to use 8 -character borders.

I'm not aware of gedit having a setting for this.
Try a free text editor instead, e.g. geany, or kate

**Things to check:**
`$ man tabs`
`$ od -t x1z textfile | less`
https://www.google.se/search?q=tabs+2+spaces+deb

Comment: Gedit does have a setting. In the bottom-bar of the gedit window you can select the tab width (2, 4, or 8 spaces), and you can select whether to use spaces or a tab character. This is on a per file basis. You can also set the default behavior for all files using Gedit's Preferences dialog, on the Editor tab.